# TextMate can't find my RSpec gem in opt (from macports)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, textmate, macports, textmatebundles

I know I've had this problem before so I'm really frustrated.

I've got the Ruby RSpec bundle installed for TextMate, but when I Run Behaviour Description or Run Focused Example I get this wonderful error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827:
in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rspec (>= 1.1.0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:261:
in `activate' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby
/1.8/rubygems.rb:68:in `gem' from /Users/simon/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Ruby
RSpec.tmbundle/Support/lib/spec_mate.rb:13 from /tmp/temp_textmate.oWRPUR:3:in `require'
from /tmp/temp_textmate.oWRPUR:3
```

(I added linebreaks to make it readable)

I'm using macports so my rspec gem is installed in `/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/`. Why isn't it finding it?

In Preferences > Advanced > Shell Variables my `TM_RUBY` is set to `/opt/local/bin/ruby`. I also tried the trick here:

http://dnite.org/2007/8/28/textmate-and-your-environment-variables/

... which didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only solution I could find is unsubtle but works.

```
% cd /usr/bin/
% sudo mv ruby moved.ruby
% sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/ruby ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a TM_RSPEC_HOME variable pointing to your rspec install.

Comment: When I do that, I get a different error: "Missing the Rails 2.3.2 gem". I think that the RSpec bundle is in fact trying to use the wrong ruby. (I do have TM_RUBY set to /opt/local/bin/ruby but that isn't helping)

Comment: you should also link /usr/bin/gem & /usr/bin/irb to the macports one.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this same issue with a new install of TextMate and Snow Leopard. Go to Preferences > Advanced > Shell Variables, and along with TM_RUBY, make sure PATH is set so the ruby you want it to find is first.

I use rvm, so this symbolic link...

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby -> /Users/jjulian/.rvm/bin/textmate_ruby
```

...allows me to tell textmate that the first entry on my PATH is `/usr/local/bin`:

```
PATH  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Now it always finds `.rvm/bin/textmate_ruby`